# Android: Converting OnItemClick to OnClickListener

Tags: android

Previously I have this OnItemClick method which enables the user to click the row on the listview and leads to a new activity bringing some attributes (texts,image) to a new activity

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        listIntent.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
        listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                .toString(id)));
        startActivity(listIntent);

    }
```

But now I just implemented a 'View' to my CursorAdapter. It's impossible to implement `onItemClick` to the row layout, what I can do is implement onClick to it. But I'm having trouble converting the method content from my previous OnItemClick to `OnClickListener`.
I need the method to behave like my previous OnItemClick.

Because I need to declare some attributes like position, and id which aren't available in this method.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {


                 }
                });
```

Therefore I need the `OnClickListener` method to behave like my previous `OnItemClick`.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to handle the click event with an OnItemClick listener.  Make sure that nothing in your View is catching or handling the click event.    Set clickable to false so that the click event is populated up the chain and caught by the OnItemClick handler.

Comment: I dont have any idea what to do with the 'long id' I had on OnItemClick, when I implement the same code to my OnClickListener, it asks me for it otherwise it gives me an error. Can you help me maybe by providing the code based on what I have? Thanks